# How to get multiple values of a column based on max value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

So I have this table

[image]

I want to "print" the Surnames of those who are in the same semester but also their grade is maximum 2 points below their semester's highest grade. For example for the semester 4 the surnames needed are "Παπαβασιλείου" (highest grade = 9) and "Βαλκανιώτης" (grade = 7 >= (9 - 2))

what I've done is this code but it does not satisfy my criteria

```
SELECT GRADE as GRADE, SURNAME FROM pinakas2 
WHERE GRADE >= ((SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM pinakas2) - 2) 
GROUP BY SEMESTER ORDER BY GRADE DESC
```

It gives as a result this:

[image]

Comment: Why the GROUP BY semester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY`, do `ORDER BY semester` instead:

```
SELECT GRADE as GRADE, SURNAME
FROM pinakas2 
WHERE GRADE >= ((SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM pinakas2) - 2) 
ORDER BY SEMESTER, GRADE DESC
```

If you want highest grade per semester minus 2, do a correlated sub-query instead:

```
SELECT GRADE as GRADE, SURNAME
FROM pinakas2 p1
WHERE GRADE >= ((SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM pinakas2 p2
                 where p1.semester = p2.semester) - 2) 
ORDER BY SEMESTER, GRADE DESC
```

Comment: I tried it, you are right about the group by, I removed it and copied your code instead but the problem is that it excludes some of the results, for example the "Βαλκανιώτης" grade. The only grades that it shows are higher than 8 only.

Comment: But didn't you say max grade - 2, which is 10 -2 = 8? Or did you mean per semster?

Comment: Per semester, sorry my english are bad, you are totally right to get confused.

Comment: Then my second select will do fine!

Comment: I've tried something similar before but it gives me an error "Unknown column 'p2.semester' in 'where clause'". I'm using phpMyAdmin to run your code..

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need a subquery to find out the highest grade in the semester, as follows:

```
        SELECT MAX(GRADE) GRADE, SEMESTER
          FROM pinakas2
         GROUP BY SEMESTER
```

Then you need to use that to retrieve the students you want:

```
  SELECT a.GRADE, a.SURNAME, a.SEMESTER
    FROM pinakas2 a
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(GRADE) GRADE, SEMESTER
          FROM pinakas2
         GROUP BY SEMESTER
         ) b ON a.SEMESTER = b.SEMESTER AND a.GRADE >= b.GRADE - 2
   ORDER BY a.SURNAME, a.GRADE
```

If for some reason you don't care about the semester in which this occurred, do this instead.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT a.GRADE, a.SURNAME
    FROM pinakas2 a
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(GRADE) GRADE, SEMESTER
          FROM pinakas2
         GROUP BY SEMESTER
         ) b ON a.SEMESTER = b.SEMESTER AND a.GRADE >= b.GRADE - 2
   ORDER BY a.SURNAME, a.GRADE
```

Comment: Sorry if this will sound stupid because I'm new to SQL but it gives me an error like this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT a.GRADE, a.SURNAME, a.SEMESTER
    FROM pinakas2 a
    JOIN (
        SEL' at line 4"